# In Excel, how do I convert a fractional number to text like "234.5" but a whole number to text like "234"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, how do I convert a fractional number to text like "234.5" but a whole number to text like "234"? If I do =text(234, "0.0") it gives 234.0, but I want "234". If I do =text(234.5, "0") it gives 235,but I want 234.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want numbers to be changed to Text format without other changes in appearance one way is with:

```
=A1&""
```

Comment: This works for me - also with `TEXT` function, `=TEXT(A1,"general")`

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what I need. It lets me control the rounding separately from the text display.